# How to select the first row from group by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am writing a program for amateur radio. Some `callsigns` will appear more than once in the data but the `qsodate` will be different. I only want the first occurrence of a call sign after a given date.

The query

```
select distinct 
  a.callsign, 
  a.SKCC_Number,
  a.qsodate,
  b.name,
  a.SPC,
  a.Band
from qso a, skccdata b
where SKCC_Number like '%[CTS]%'
  AND QSODate > = '2014-08-01'
  and b.callsign = a.callsign
order by a.QSODate
```

The problem:

Because `contacts` occur on different dates, I get all of the contacts - I have tried adding `min(a.qsodate)` to get only the first but then I run into all sorts of issues regarding grouping.

This query will be in a stored procedure, so creating temp tables or cursors will not be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to get the first row with the first date, like this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    select 
      a.callsign, 
      a.SKCC_Number,
      a.qsodate,
      b.name,
      a.SPC,
      a.Band,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.callsign ORDER BY a.QSODate) AS RN
    from qso a,skccdata b
    where SKCC_Number like '%[CTS]%'
      AND QSODate > = '2014-08-01'
      and b.callsign = a.callsign
) 
SELECT * 
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN = 1;
```

---

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.callsign ORDER BY a.QSODate)` will give you a ranking number for each group of `callsign` ordered by `QSODate`, then the `WHERE RN = 1` will eliminate all the rows except the first one which has the minimum `QSODate`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried starting your query with `SELECT TOP 1` ...(fields)  Then you will only get one row.  You can use `TOP x` .... for x number of rows, or `TOP 50 PERCENT` for the top half of the rows, etc.  Then you can eliminate `DISTINCT` in this case

EDIT: misunderstood question.  How about this?

```
select 
  a.callsign, 
  a.SKCC_Number,
  a.qsodate,
  (SELECT TOP 1 b.name FROM skccdata b WHERE b.callsign = a.callsign) as NAME,
  a.SPC,
  a.Band
from qso a
where SKCC_Number like '%[CTS]%'
  AND QSODate > = '2014-08-01'
GROUP BY a.QSODate, a.callsign, a.SKCC_Number, a.SPC, a.Band
order by a.QSODate
```

and add callsign to your where clause to isolate callsigns

Comment: This won't work as the OP wants the TOP 1 row for each group, not the TOP 1 for the end result set.